# Console application integrating Slack Webhooks, but compiler says namespace "Slack" cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2017, slack

I am creating a simple console app that on run, it checks a date and sends a notification via email, and it works. Now I tried adding the Slack Webhooks package through the NuGet package manager and implemented a simple post function from the package to send the notification to a Slack channel, and on build and debug it also works perfectly.

However, on compiling the project, this message appears:

> Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Slack'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I tried reinstalling the package, even though I clearly see the "missing" reference in the Solution Explorer, but the problem persists. I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, have not changed Framework version for this project (as I've seen that some solutions propose downgrading the project's framework, presumably to enforce compatibility)

How can I really solve this problem, though?

Comment: Did you import it at the top of your program? You can also right click (or hit `Ctrl` + `.`) to see suggested solutions.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another class or namespace named `Slack` in your project?

Comment: There are no suggested solutions. The whole problem is that the file, the code, is perfectly fine, but the compiler throws an error. I am pretty sure I do not have a repeat Slack class/namespace anywhere.

Comment: Can you share the solution somewhere (e.g. GitHub)? Also, can you explain what you consider the difference between "build" and "compile" to be? (One works and the other doesn't.)

Comment: On Visual Studio, I run an option called Build Solution which yields no errors. Then I try running the application with F5, it runs with no issues. But then I try to generate a .exe using Visual Studio's command line and the `csc` command, and that's where the error appears.